# buildozer android

Tags: python, kivy

amigos me pueden ayudar estoy tratando de crear una apk para android ya realice la instalacion de todas las dependencias pero apenas le doy el comando de crear el apk me genera este error me pueden ayudar estoy utilizando un entorno virtual

```
# Command failed: /home/dev-chavita/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LANG = 'es_CO.UTF-8'
#     USERNAME = 'root'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     PS1 = '(k36) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ '
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     LANGUAGE = 'es_CO:es'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/root'
#     SUDO_UID = '1000'
#     SUDO_GID = '1000'
#     SUDO_COMMAND = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer android debug'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     LOGNAME = 'root'
#     USER = 'root'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     PATH = '/home/dev-chavita/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin'
#     HOME = '/home/dev-chavita'
#     SUDO_USER = 'dev-chavita'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

espero me puedan orientar mas gracias amigos utilizo ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Eleva el  `log_level` a 2 en tu [buildozer.spec](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kivy/buildozer/master/buildozer/default.spec) (`log_level = 2`, está en el campo `[buildozer]`
) y muestra la salida al intentar ejecutar de nuevo.

Comment: Amigo ya esta en nivel 2 
`[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1`

Comment: Ok, si usas el comando `debug`, (`buildozer android debug deploy run`) antes de la linea `# Command failed: /...` debería haber más información de la traza del error... Suelen ser problemas con el jdk.

Comment: hablas de estos datos `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
 ... 5 more`
espero que si amigo o de cuales?

Comment: Si, mirate https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/876 a ver si te ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como resolvi este problema fue realizando la desistalacion de todos los paquetes de jdk ausolutamente todos y realice la instalacion del paquete jdk version 8 y funciono perfectamente espero les pueda servir y orientar mas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron.